# Как использовать возможность автоматического merge изменений сервером непрерывной интеграции?

Tags: jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, teamcity

У TeamCity есть билд фича Automatic merge. Она позволяет сделать merge изменений коммита в определенную ветку (интеграции). Каждый раз когда кто-нибудь делает коммит который проходит все тесты можно этот коммит автоматически влить в ветку интерграции и, если не получилось, выдать ошибку что при мерже возникли конфликты что позволит команде оперативно среагировать.

Вопрос: Что делать после того как оказалось что при слиянии возникли конфликты?

По идее, если программист работает в `feature` ветке, он должен намержить ветку на себя и разрулить конфликты. Только это не девелоп. В девелоп нельзя автоматом мержить. Не могу разобраться как эту фичу грамотно заюзать. Какие есть use-cases?

Comment: `когда кто-нибудь делает коммит` - точно коммит, а не мерж-реквест? Не всегда коммит означает, что фича завершена и готова к тестированию. Если коммит автоматически будет мержиться, это простимулирует разработчиков коммитить реже (или не пушить на remote), что чревато потерей результатов работы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin идея в том чтобы обнаруживать конфликты как можно раньше. Автоматический мерж идет в отдельную ветку никак не связанную с разработкой, поэтому это никак не влияет на процесс работы. Вполне возможно что я что-то не так понял и использую этот инструмент не так как надо. Отсюда и вопрос :)

Comment: конфликт слияния это вроде бы штатная ситуация. Вы хотите чтобы каждый раз разработчик ребейз делал? В чем цель?

Comment: Цель понять как можно использовать фичу `Automatic merge` в TeamCity. Зачем она там. Какие есть сценарии использования. Я придумал один из них - показывать что коммит не прошел автоматический мерж, что означает что по-хорошему надо по быстрому разрулить проблему пока конфликт горяченький. Возможно это не так используется. Не знаю :)

Comment: @Onedev.Link, а разве система интеграционного тестирования не рассылает уведомления о неудаче? Зачем куда-либо вливать заведомо неработоспособную feature-ветку? Ведь каждое успешное слияние такой ветки всё больше «ломает» ветку интеграции.

Comment: @Arhad вливаются только те билды которые прошли все тесты. То есть ошибка может возникнуть только в результате конфликта слияния. И да, каждое успешное слияние отдаляет ветку интеграции от ветки девелоп. Но использовать ветку интеграции чтобы накатить изменения на свою ветку нельзя - мало ли что там автоматически смержилось. Вот и не понятно что делать если мы напоролись на конфликт. И когда его разрешать. Предполагаю все же что этот инструмент используется немного не так.

Comment: Конфликт при мерже - результат не верно поставленных задач разработчикам :-)

Comment: @Чад предпочитаю программистам ставить цели, а не задачи :) Декомпозировать проблему на задачи программисты вполне могут самостоятельно. Впервые встречаю такую формулировку проблемы конфликтов, можете назвать первоисточник?

Comment: @Onedev.Link моя личная формулировка. Цели ставятся тим лидам и ответственным за проект. Но суть не меняется - в идеальной разработке, каждая конечная задача (из которых состоят общие) не должна пересекаться по коду с другими задачами. А если есть пересечение (по сути пересечение мнений) - это лучше решать путём экстремального программирования.

Comment: @Чад весьма спорно. Понятно, что если конфликты случаются на каждом втором мерже, то есть проблема. Но время от времени -- это нормально. А если вы дробите и ставите задачи так, чтобы они не пересекались по коду, то весьма вероятно, что занимаетесь микроменеджментом.

Comment: @andreycha ну, время от времени, править код боевого серера в реальном времени без самого процесса - тоже нормально.Но это не нормально в принципе, если хочется работать по правильному тех процессу.Я не дроблю и ставлю - я требую чтобы так было. Ещё на этапе прототипирования и разработки архитектуры. Это действительно прекрасно, если удаётся построить процесс разработки именно так. Конфликты при мёрже - это симптом который говорит что, что-то в процессе было сделано не так - или сроки ушли, или требования ушли, или реализация кривая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне видится два варианта использования автоматического мержа:

- Если вы используете фича/багфикс бранчи, но при этом в вашем процессе нет пулл-реквестов/интеграционной ветки, т.е. вы готовы сразу мержить в мастер. Это позволяет достичь изолированности изменений и их автоматической интеграции. (Хотя лично мне такая модель представляется сомнительной, особенно для достаточно больших изменений, поскольку заставляет делать локальные коммиты без пуша, а это может быть чревато.)
- Если вы используете интеграционный бранч, куда вливаются фича/багфикс бранчи. Изменения тестируются, а после этого вливаются в мастер.

Во втором случае интеграционный бранч по сути является копией мастера с добавленными изменениями. Поэтому при вливании в интеграционный бранч конфликты могут возникнуть по двум причинам:

- изменения конфликтуют с мастером
- изменения конфликтуют с изменениями из другого фича/багфикс бранча, которые были влиты в интеграционную ветку, но еще не попали в мастер

В обоих случаях разруливать конфликт достаточно мержем из интеграционной ветки. Первый случай очевиден -- конфликтующие изменения из мастера есть и в интеграционной ветке. Второй случай тоже очевиден -- без "зеленой" интеграционной ветки работа дальше не пойдет. И тут действует стандартное правило -- кто последний коммитит, тот и мержит :).

---

> идея в том чтобы обнаруживать конфликты как можно раньше.

Тогда может стоит просто добавить мерж из мастера в фича/багфикс ветку при каждом билде? Если говорить о TeamCity, то первым шагом билда добавляете следующий код:

```
git remote set-url origin %repo_url%
if NOT %teamcity.build.branch.is_default%==true git fetch 
if NOT %teamcity.build.branch.is_default%==true git merge origin/master
```

Это гарантированно будет обнаруживать конфликты сразу. Мастер будет всегда "зеленый", вы не будете получать конфликты из-за того, что кто-то залил конфликтующие изменения в интеграционную ветку.